# Error connection mandrill (Laravel)

Tags: php, email, laravel, mandrill

I have an issue with the mandrill API, I got this message :

`Failed to connect to mandrillapp.com port 443: Connection timed out`

It's works on my production server (ex mysite.com), but not on my dev server (ex mysite.com:8080).

The two servers have same config by the way.

Anyone knows why I got this issue ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your hosting provider or internet provider (ISP) allows
   outbound SMTP connections. Some shared hosting providers only allow
   outbound SMTP connections on dedicated servers, while others block
   them completely. In some cases, hosting providers might redirect the
   connection, so instead of connecting to smtp.mandrillapp.com, you
   connect to their local server instead.
2. Make sure the port you've selected is one that your hosting provider
   or ISP has available for outbound SMTP connections. Some hosts block
   all connections on port 25, for example, so you can try using a
   different supported port.
3. Double check that you're using a valid API key to connect via SMTP,
   and not the password that's used to log in to Mandrill's web
   application.
4. If you're using Postfix, make sure that you have an SASL library
   (like libsasl2 or cyrus) installed and that it's up to date.
   Otherwise, you may be connecting but not passing authentication
   credentials.
5. For other SMTP libraries, make sure you're using LOGIN or PLAIN
   authentication methods.

> Once you've confirmed all of the above, if you're still seeing issues,
>   please enable additional logging in your SMTP program or library. If
>   you're using an integration, contact the integration developer for
>   information on configuring logging of the SMTP conversation.

**Where do I find my SMTP credentials?**

> After you create a Mandrill account, get your SMTP credentials on the
>   SMTP & API Info page in your account.
>
> The SMTP password is any active API key for your account, not the
>   password used to log in to Mandrill. The credentials list port 587,
>   but any port supported by Mandrill will work, and there's no
>   configuration change needed within Mandrill to activate one of the
>   alternate ports.

**Which SMTP ports can I use?**

> You can use port 25, 587, or 2525 if you're not encrypting the
>   communication between your system and Mandrill or if you want to use
>   the STARTTLS extension (also known as TLS encryption). SSL is
>   supported on port 465.
>
> ISPs may redirect traffic on certain ports, so it's up to you which
>   port you use.